# Caching List.js Results - Reload filtered results on browser back button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, list.js, acfpro

I have a site where I am using `List.js` to filter between For Sale and To Let properties.

The JS for this is as so:

```
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'status' ],
};

var hackerList = new List('property-list', options);
```

And I'm using a select box to fill a hidden input with the value to filter the list by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeValue() {
        var option = document.getElementById('filter').value;

        if (option == "Sale") {
            document.getElementById('field').value = "Sale";
            document.getElementById("field").focus();
        } else if (option == "Letting") {
            document.getElementById('field').value = "Letting";
            document.getElementById("field").focus();
        } else if (option == "") {
            document.getElementById('field').value = "";
            document.getElementById("field").focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```

I need to some how store the results of this using `WebStorage` or `Cookies`, but no matter what I try the second I add more code the filter stops working all together.

When The user presses the back button from a property listing to the listings page, it needs to show the results they'd already filtered.

Any ideas?

---

Each result is listed in an li.  I am using Wordpress and ACF Pro to do this:

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li class="col-md-4 <?php if( has_term( 'For Sale', 'propertycategories' ) ) {?>sale <?php } ?><?php if( has_term( 'To Let', 'propertycategories' ) ) {?>let<?php } ?>">
        <p class="status hidden"><?php if( has_term( 'For Sale', 'propertycategories' ) ) {?>Sale<?php } ?><?php if( has_term( 'To Let', 'propertycategories' ) ) {?>Letting<?php } ?></p>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="property wow fadeIn">
            <div class="property-image-container <?php the_field('offer_status2'); ?>">
                <span class="badge"><?php the_field('offer_status2'); ?> </span>
                <img class="property-image" src="<?php the_field('property_image_1'); ?>" alt=" "/>
            </div>
            <div class="property-details-container">
                <span class="float-left"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                <span class="float-right">£<?php echo number_format( get_field('price') ); ?>             <?php if( has_term( 'To Let', 'propertycategories' ) ) {?>PCM <?php } ?></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I hope this helps.  Thanks again for your help already really appreciated!

Comment: What is the results object, it's json for ex ? Do you have a an example ?

Comment: Have updated with the results li above, hope this helps explain!

Answer (score 0):

you could "store" the information about the filter applied in the url using [window.history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method). For example:

```
var option = document.getElementById('filter').value;
var url = `${window.location.href}?filter=${option}`;
window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
```

The url will be added to the user history and so when he click the back button from a property listing the URL will contain the parameter previously "stored".

So in this case the parameter will be something like: http://example.com/?filter=Sale

Now you can either use PHP/JS to apply the filter.

Comment: Hi Alessandro thanks for your help,  I am using List.js which helps filter a list using ajax, so unfortunately the url does not get updated.